# is there a way to make batch code more compact?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a 1 line code which downloads files and executes them. I have tried the **&** and **&&** method to run more commands one after another. but I am having a hard time trying to put the second line with the first one using **&**.

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/-----/unixC/archive/main.zip -OutFile I.zip" & powershell Expand-Archive I.zip & for /f %%a IN ('dir "I\unixC-main" /b') do move "I\unixC-main\%%a" "%cd%\"
@RD /S /Q "I" & del /q /f I.zip log.txt README.md & start unixC.bat & start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
```

Is there any way to make this snippet of code even shorter? and more compact?

Rasil

Comment: I can tell you that putting multiple lines on the same one separated by ampersands does not make a batch file more compact, shorter or easier to read/understand. So your two lines are not better than the eight they're trying to represent.

Comment: If you have the ability to call to powershell, then why not just create a powershell script? And why switch back and forth between powershell and batch? You could do all of this in a single powershell script.

Comment: @ChadBaldwin I only work with batch and got help on the PowerShell part I have no idea on how to move files, delete folders.

Comment: @Rasil ah okay. Maybe this is a good opportunity to learn then :)

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, the whole thing could be done in powershell.  Semicolon seperates commands.  -command is the default so you can leave it out.  Wget is a powershell alias for invoke-webrequest.

```
powershell wget https://github.com/-----/unixC/archive/main.zip -OutFile I.zip; Expand-Archive I.zip
```

Example powershell replacement for the whole thing:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/-----/unixC/archive/main.zip -OutFile I.zip
Expand-Archive I.zip
move-item i\unixC-main\* $pwd  # $pwd is optional
remove-item -recurse i
remove-item -force i.zip,log.txt,readme.md
.\unixC.bat
remove-item $args[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parenthesising `for /f %%a IN ('dir "I\unixC-main" /b') do move "I\unixC-main\%%a" "%cd%\"` and then append the `&{second line}`

Comment: i did try that but it doesnt seem to work :/ `powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/-----/unixC/archive/main.zip -OutFile I.zip" & powershell Expand-Archive I.zip & for /f %%a IN ('dir "I\unixC-main" /b') do move "I\unixC-main\%%a" "%cd%\" & @RD /S /Q "I" & del /q /f I.zip log.txt README.md & start unixC.bat & start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b` it just seems to move only 1 file and a error pops up saying that it couldn't find the file specified

Comment: If what you've posted in your comment is the code you used, then you've ignored the parenthesising part. `...I.zip & ( for /f %%a IN ('dir "I\unixC-main" /b') do move "I\unixC-main\%%a" "%cd%\" ) & @RD ...` - notice the parenthesis-pair.

Comment: yup this worked after your correction! `powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/-----/unixC/archive/main.zip -OutFile I.zip" & powershell Expand-Archive I.zip & ( for /f %%a IN ('dir "I\unixC-main" /b') do move "I\unixC-main\%%a" "%cd%\" ) & @RD /S /Q "I" & del /q /f I.zip log.txt README.md & start unixC.bat & start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
`